# include javascript Multiple files in wordpress through script.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i have `script.js` file for html to wordpress conversion. In html it works, but in wordpress it does not work. This file contains slider, menus etc, I enable to convert html to wordpress without this file, the file has following contents

```
function include(scriptUrl) {
    document.write('<script src="' + scriptUrl + '"></script>');
}

function isIE() {
    var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;
};

/* cookie.JS
 ========================================================*/
include('js/jquery.cookie.js');

/* Easing library
 ========================================================*/
include('js/jquery.easing.1.3.js');

/* Stick up menus
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = $('html');
    if (o.hasClass('desktop')) {
        include('js/tmstickup.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#stuck_container').TMStickUp({})
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

/* ToTop
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = $('html');
    if (o.hasClass('desktop')) {
        include('js/jquery.ui.totop.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $().UItoTop({
                easingType: 'easeOutQuart',
                containerClass: 'toTop fa fa-arrow-up'
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

/* EqualHeights
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = $('[data-equal-group]');
    if (o.length > 0) {
        include('js/jquery.equalheights.js');
    }
})(jQuery);

/* SMOOTH SCROLLIG
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = $('html');
    if (o.hasClass('desktop')) {
        include('js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js');
        include('js/jquery.simplr.smoothscroll.min.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.srSmoothscroll({
                step: 150,
                speed: 800
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

/* Copyright Year
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#copyright-year").text((new Date).getFullYear());
    });
})(jQuery);


/* Superfish menus
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    include('js/superfish.js');    
})(jQuery);

/* Navbar
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    include('js/jquery.rd-navbar.js');
})(jQuery);

/* Camera
========================================================*/
;(function ($) {
var o = $('#camera');
    if (o.length > 0) {
        if (!(isIE() && (isIE() > 9))) {
            include('js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js');
        }

        include('js/camera.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            o.camera({
                autoAdvance: true,
                height: '25.8536%',
                minHeight: '300px',
                pagination: true,
                thumbnails: false,
                playPause: false,
                hover: false,
                loader: 'none',
                navigation: false,
                navigationHover: false,
                mobileNavHover: false,
                fx: 'simpleFade'
            })
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

/* FancyBox
========================================================*/
;(function ($) {
    var o = $('.thumb');
    if (o.length > 0) {
        include('js/jquery.fancybox.js');
        include('js/jquery.fancybox-media.js');
        include('js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js');
        $(document).ready(function () {
            o.fancybox();
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

/* Parallax 
=============================================*/ 
;(function ($) { 
    include('js/jquery.rd-parallax.js'); 
})(jQuery);


/* Google Map
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = document.getElementById("google-map");
    if (o) {
        include('//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false');
        include('js/jquery.rd-google-map.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var o = $('#google-map');
            if (o.length > 0) {
                var styleArray = [
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#2c2e33"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": 7
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 19
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "landscape",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#ffffff"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -100
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 100
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#ffffff"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -100
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 100
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "off"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#bbc0c4"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -93
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 31
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "labels",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#bbc0c4"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -93
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 31
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road.arterial",
                        "elementType": "labels",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#bbc0c4"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -93
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": -2
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road.local",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#e9ebed"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -90
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": -8
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "transit",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#e9ebed"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": 10
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 69
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "water",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#e9ebed"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -78
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 67
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]

                o.googleMap({
                    styles: styleArray,
                });
            }
        });
    }
})
(jQuery);

(function ($) {
    var o = document.getElementById("google-map2");
    if (o) {
        include('//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false');
        include('js/jquery.rd-google-map.js');

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var o = $('#google-map2');
            if (o.length > 0) {
                var styleArray = [
                    {
                        "featureType": "administrative.locality",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#2c2e33"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": 7
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 19
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "landscape",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#ffffff"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -100
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 100
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#ffffff"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -100
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 100
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "off"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#bbc0c4"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -93
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 31
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "labels",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#bbc0c4"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -93
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 31
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road.arterial",
                        "elementType": "labels",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#bbc0c4"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -93
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": -2
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "road.local",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#e9ebed"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -90
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": -8
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "transit",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#e9ebed"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": 10
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 69
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "on"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "featureType": "water",
                        "elementType": "all",
                        "stylers": [
                            {
                                "hue": "#e9ebed"
                            },
                            {
                                "saturation": -78
                            },
                            {
                                "lightness": 67
                            },
                            {
                                "visibility": "simplified"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]

                o.googleMap({
                    styles: styleArray,
                });
            }
        });
    }
})
(jQuery);

/* WOW
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = $('html');

    if ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') == -1 ) || (isIE() && isIE() > 9)) {
        if (o.hasClass('desktop')) {
            include('js/wow.js');

            $(document).ready(function () {
                new WOW().init();
            });
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

/* Contact Form
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    var o = $('#contact-form');
    if (o.length > 0) {
        include('js/modal.js');
        include('js/TMForm.js'); 

        if($('#contact-form .recaptcha').length > 0){
            include('../www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js');
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

/* Search.js
 ========================================================*/
;
(function ($) {
    include('js/TMSearch.js');
})(jQuery);

/* Orientation tablet fix
 ========================================================*/
$(function () {
    // IPad/IPhone
    var viewportmeta = document.querySelector && document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]'),
        ua = navigator.userAgent,

        gestureStart = function () {
            viewportmeta.content = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=1.6, initial-scale=1.0";
        },

        scaleFix = function () {
            if (viewportmeta && /iPhone|iPad/.test(ua) && !/Opera Mini/.test(ua)) {
                viewportmeta.content = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0";
                document.addEventListener("gesturestart", gestureStart, false);
            }
        };

    scaleFix();
    // Menu Android
    if (window.orientation != undefined) {
        var regM = /ipod|ipad|iphone/gi,
            result = ua.match(regM);
        if (!result) {
            $('.sf-menus li').each(function () {
                if ($(">ul", this)[0]) {
                    $(">a", this).toggle(
                        function () {
                            return false;
                        },
                        function () {
                            window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
                        }
                    );
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLocaleLowerCase(),
    regV = /ipod|ipad|iphone/gi,
    result = ua.match(regV),
    userScale = "";
if (!result) {
    userScale = ",user-scalable=0"
}
document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0' + userScale + '">');
```

i tried many methods. how should i include this to work in a wordpress in proper way?

Answer (score 1):

If you can also load the scripts from PHP, you should use the following function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Otherwise if you have to load them from within your javascript you could use the following method. You are using jQuery so you could use the following jQuery function to load(not necessarily executing):

```
$.getScript("script.js", function(){});
```

See more information in this stack post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/5567106